# How can I modify the pixel data of a UIImage on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, pixel

I want to modify a UIImage on a pixel-by-pixel basis.

I've found a couple of posts here and elsewhere about accessing the image data as a char* pointer.  My twist is that I want to modify this data and then create a new UIImage based on my pixel data.  Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help you: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html

ps. you need tho login to the iphone developer page, if you want to reed the page :)

Comment: Thanks; saw that one already.  It explains how to access the pixel data, but not how to create a new image from modified pixel data.

Comment: I guess you can make an NSData object out of the pixel array and afterwards using the NSData object for creating the UIImage.