# iPhone, modify UIImage to a target average color

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uiimage

I need for a project to modify UIImage.
Here are steps I have to follow
- I extract the average color of the image by taking several points in the image and calculating the average R, G and B
- The next step is to modify the image in order to have a new average R, G and B for the modified image. This new R, G and B is given, the thing I do not know how to do is:
how to modify an UIImage in order to pass from an existing average RGB value to a given RGB value.

I am not sure to be very clear. Do not hesitate to ask me if this is not the case.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the lower level Core Graphics API to access the image's pixel data.

There have been a number of questions on that before, like for example these two:

- [How to get the RGB values for a pixel on an image on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144250/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-for-a-pixel-on-an-image-on-the-iphone)
- [How can I modify the pixel data of a UIImage on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026582/how-can-i-modify-the-pixel-data-of-a-uiimage-on-the-iphone)

The latter contains a link to a good document from Apple, titled 'Getting the pixel data from a CGImage object'.

Comment: I still don't see how to modify there data... perhaps I'm missing it but the second question does not have an answer.